# Index match function within range

Tags: excel, vba

At first it looked like a easy one, however I'm stuck on trying to find a way how to solve. The idea is to find C3 which matches C1 and falls in the given range C2. Basicaly B 40 shuold return -0.15. Any sugesstions ?

Image:

[image: Example]

I have tried Index match function and it worked fine without ranges. C2 values are constant every time, only C3 cuold change.

Comment: This does not make any sense at all. You have to clarify by adding code and a visual representation of what your expected outcome is.

Comment: Your question is still not clear.. There is no 40 in the image. What are you trying to achieve? Where is the input cell and output cell?

Comment: Are the numbers in C2 always the same repetition? `0,20,50,75,100`?

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach step by step

Based on this data:

[image]

1) Get the letter from mixed cell

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(F4,0,""""),1,""""),2,""""),3,""""),4,""""),5,""""),6,""""),7,""""),8,""""),9,"""")
```

2) Get the number from mixed cell:

```
=VALUE(MID(F4,FIND(F6,F4)+1,LEN(F4)))
```

3) Look for first letter:

```
=MATCH(F6,$A$4:$A$13,0)
```

4) Count letter:

```
=COUNTIF($A$4:$A$13,F6)
```

5) Reference to letter range (I wrapped it-in the screenshot- with Sum() in order to test it):

```
=OFFSET($A$4,F8-1,1,F9,2)
```

6) Return value:

```
=VLOOKUP(F7,OFFSET($A$4,F8-1,1,F9,2),2,TRUE)
```

All at once:

```
=VLOOKUP(VALUE(MID(F4,FIND(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(F4,0,""),1,""),2,""),3,""),4,""),5,""),6,""),7,""),8,""),9,""),F4)+1,LEN(F4))),OFFSET($A$4,MATCH(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(F4,0,""),1,""),2,""),3,""),4,""),5,""),6,""),7,""),8,""),9,""),$A$4:$A$13,0)-1,1,COUNTIF($A$4:$A$13,SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(F4,0,""),1,""),2,""),3,""),4,""),5,""),6,""),7,""),8,""),9,"")),2),2,TRUE)
```